# Any side-effects to changing Wix Directory element Id value?

Tags: wix

I've inherited a Wix-based installer. Most of the Directory@Id attributes are generated in the form Id="dirE039ABA27AC02A3F578F38F62EAD8474". Are there any side effects to changing that value in  and every place the ID is referenced? I am hoping this isn't, for example, like a Component@Guid which must not be changed otherwise Windows Installer won't know its the same component.

Are all Wix @Id attributes similar? I'm hoping they are just internal Wix linkages and have no semantics for Windows Installer.

I want to change IDs from gibberish to something self-documenting.

Comment: To clarify, the side effects that matter to me are those affecting upgrades for customers who have a previous version installed.

Answer (score 0):

`Directory/@Id` values end up in the .msi as specified.

Comment: It's a side effect but does that affect upgrades?

Comment: That's not a side effect; it's a direct part of references and component identity.

Comment: You can potentially break upgrades and patches if you've already shipped a previous version, and that's because the ID is a key and the MSI is a relational database.

Comment: It would absolutely break patching and it could affect upgrades too.